# A non-smooth map between manifolds (codomain extended)

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In my introductory book on differentiable manifolds, there are some results that puzzle me quite a bit. First of all, there's the following corollary,

[image]

Here, we have defined a submanifold as a subset which is a differential manifold itself, and such that the inclusion $i$ map is smooth and the differential $di_p$ is injective for each $p$ in the subset.

In my particular case, I am trying to use the above to derive a contradiction. I have my $L$ to be $\mathcal{S}^1$ and $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, both differentiable manifolds. I have a set $N$ for which I have a smooth map $f: L\rightarrow N$. I want to prove it is $\textit{not}$ a submanifold by assuming it is, then deriving that $f:L\rightarrow M$ is $\textit{not}$ smooth, thus obtaining a contradiction.

However, I can not intuitively think of an example of a map which is smooth into some codomain $N$, a subset of $M$, but where the map is not smooth if codomain is extended to $M$. Can anyone help me?

PS: as $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, the definition of smoothness I use is this:

[image]

Comment: What is your set $N$? What is its differentiable structure?

Comment: My set N is the boundary of an unspecified square, I think the one I worked with was $\{(x,y)\,:\,max(|x|,|y|)=1\}$. But I wanted to ask a more general question as I thought that'd be more useful to all of you.